# Providing "Add to Calendar" link

Tags: .net, asp.net, calendar, icalendar, vcalendar

I am trying to add an "Add to Calendar" link to my web app.  I've looked at a bunch of questions over the last couple of years and now I am more confused than ever.

There is iCal, vCal, vCalendar, iCalendar 1.0, iCalendar 2.0, etc... formats.  I can't even tell whether some of these refer to the same thing.

What is the current method of providing an "Add to Calendar" link?  I'd prefer it if it worked on at least Outlook, Android, whatever calendar app comes with the Mac.  And I already know that iPhone doesn't have this functionality, period.

Added bonus if you provide a link to a .NET library (with source available) that already does this.

Thanks.

Comment: Added bonus? Where? Don't see a bounty. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RFC 5545 (AKA iCal, iCalendar) would probably be your best bet for the most consistant support by e-mail clients.

I haven't used it myself, but [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) looks like a well regarded .Net implementation.

This [blog](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/sending-meeting-requests-to-outlook-via-aspnet-mail-message/) shows how to use it within ASP.Net.